# SQL : Date condition Updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update my column depending on dates from two different table. Below is my query

> ```
> UPDATE T_TRN_DEAL_DETAILS SET MATURITY_DT  = 
>  (CASE
>   WHEN (Select top 1 INS.INVOICE_DUE_DT as invoice_date  from T_TRN_INVOICE_DETAILS IND
>  INNER jOIN T_TRN_INVOICE_SUMMARY INS on IND.INVOICE_ID=INS.INVOICE_ID
>  where IND.DEAL_ID ='1234'
>  order by INS.INVOICE_DUE_DT desc ) > (Select DEAL_ID,MATURITY_DT as invoice_date from T_TRN_DEAL_DETAILS WHERE DEAL_ID ='1234')  
>  THEN (Select top 1 INS.INVOICE_DUE_DT as invoice_date  from T_TRN_INVOICE_DETAILS IND
>  INNER jOIN T_TRN_INVOICE_SUMMARY INS on IND.INVOICE_ID=INS.INVOICE_ID
>  where IND.DEAL_ID ='1234'
>  order by INS.INVOICE_DUE_DT desc) 
>  ELSE (Select DEAL_ID,MATURITY_DT as invoice_date from T_TRN_DEAL_DETAILS WHERE DEAL_ID ='DL18111213586')
>  END )  
>  WHERE DEAL_ID ='1234'
> ```

But I am getting below error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Although I am just comparing two dates.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  A non-working query does not necessarily provide useful information.

Comment: The error is pretty clear, what don't you understand about it? `(SELECT ...) > (Select DEAL_ID,MATURITY_DT` <-- You are selecting two attributes here, which do you want to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear:

a subquery must return only one column but in your ELSE breanch you have written as follow:

```
(Select DEAL_ID,MATURITY_DT as invoice_date 
from T_TRN_DEAL_DETAILS WHERE DEAL_ID ='DL18111213586')
```

So you try to return two columns. You must remove `DEAL_ID` column, because your `MATURITY_DT` is the field you want to use to update your main table.

The same error you have done in the first branch when you try to compare subqueries (>) where the second subquery returns two columns instead of one.

```
(Select DEAL_ID,MATURITY_DT as invoice_date
from T_TRN_DEAL_DETAILS WHERE DEAL_ID ='1234')
```